# ios 6 how to add facebook like button natively?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, facebook-like

Any of you knows how to implement a facebook like natively in iOS app?. I'll like to implement the button like normla IUbutton.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476898/is-it-possible-to-put-a-facebook-like-button-in-a-mobile-app-and-when-used-it-w

Comment: As far as I can see is not a duplicated. the question in the link you mention is very vague.

Comment: That is true, but I thought it may be helpful. That question wasn't really the same now that I re-read your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: Adding a Facebook Like button to a native iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110393/ios-adding-a-facebook-like-button-to-a-native-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful.  I was looking for it the other day but have not had a chance to implement.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

In short I don't believe there is a way to do it using native UIbutton.

Comment: That tutorial is from 2010. it should be some integration with iOS

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this natively at this time. The quickest way to do it is to load a webview, and navigate to the page that you wish to like.

Answer (score 0):

Lately FB opened this throught their SDK

Check this out

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/